# Copy "can't find file specified" in nested for loop

Tags: batch-file

Copying works fine everywhere else in the program, only seems to mess up inside this nested for loop. Returning `"The system cannot find the file specified."` (I assume that is the first non-switch argument passed to copy)

Running windows 10, 
*delayedexpansion* IS enabled

Further up in the program I am grabbing .pdf files from a scanning folder, creating a copy in both output and done directories. Later I realized that I needed some type of continuity check to make sure that the files in output were correct (Originally "done" was *just* used to not re-copy files I had already moved out of the "output" folder). Every pass of the program the "done" folder gets updated with the scanned files (sometimes a file is still getting loaded in from the scanner and gets partially copied).

Tried changing what I give copy in terms of file `"%%~nxA"` was one of them

```
SET useableDirectory="C:\Users\IoCalisto\Desktop\custom scan filter\output"

FOR /R "C:\Users\IoCalisto\Desktop\custom scan filter\done" %%A in (*.pdf) do (
   IF EXIST "C:\Users\IoCalisto\Desktop\custom scan filter\output\%%~nxA" (
      SET useableFile="C:\Users\IoCalisto\Desktop\custom scan filter\output\%%~nxA"

      FOR %%B in (!useableFile!) do (

         echo File: %%~zB  check: %%~zA 

         IF %%~zA EQU %%~zB echo FILE SIZE CORRECT

         IF %%~zA GTR %%~zB ( 
            copy %%A %useableDirectory%
            echo %%A
            echo %%~nxA
            echo !useableFile!
            echo %useableDirectory%
         )
         IF %%~zA LSS %%~zB echo FILE SIZE ERROR, CORRECTING IN NEXT PASS?
         echo.
      )
   )
)
```

This section of the program is a part of an integrity check to make sure files are complete. The `"C:\Users\IoCalisto\Desktop\custom scan filter\done"` directory has complete files, and I only want to copy over files that have fewer bits in the output directory. I would like to stay away from just copying everything over from the done folder, because I see this as a learning opportunity.

**EDIT**: the error happens if the `"IF %%~zA GTR %%~zB"` conditional is true. The first thing inside the body of the IF statement, is a copy command. The output from this command is in between two echo statements that both work as intended (first is outside the conditional and simply lists the file sizes).
(see attached)
[image: current cmd output]

Comment: Feel free to give me test cases to try

Comment: Feel free to explain exactly what your question is and what the specific issue is with the [tag:batch-file] code you have posted. _Your title suggests you have an error from the `copy` command, but your question body does not expand upon it!_

Comment: @Compo edited post

Comment: IoCalisto, it looks as if you're recursively searching for `pdf` files in a directory which will always have spaces in its path, so `%%A` should be doublequoted to protect those spaces! I would also recommend that you do not include doublequotes in your variable values, instead using this syntax, `Set "VariableName=StringValue"`, then include the doublequotes around those variables as necessary in use, `"%VariableName%"`.

Comment: @Compo That was it! Thanks!

Comment: @Compo I've seen that notation in substring structure before, but never thought of using it for standard declaration